# How to convert int to decimal fraction? - Java

Tags: java, int

I have such code:

```
int number1 = 20;
int number2 = number1/100;
```

I want to get percentage of number1 as 0,2 -> I suppose int should be converted into some other type. But I need 0,2 to use for BigDecimal number. How can I get this 0,2 from int number1 = 20?

int number1 = 20 has to be in that type.

Will be grateful for help.

Comment: by using floator double, not int

Comment: make `number2` a `double`?

Comment: `double number2 = number1/100.0;`

Comment: But the result is still 0.0 when I make number2 the double...

Comment: "I need 0,2 to use for BigDecimal number." no, you don't. If anything, you can create big decimal directly from `0.2`.

Comment: @JeyKey you need to divide by a `double`. `100` isn't a `double`. `100.0` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `BigDecimal` is appropriate here. You can use `BigDecimal.valueOf` in order to convert `int` to `BigDecimal`. Then, you can divide by specifying a scale and a rounding mode.

Example :

```
System.out.println(
BigDecimal.valueOf(20).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), 1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
);
```

Will display :

> 0.2

With a different scale :

```
System.out.println(
BigDecimal.valueOf(20).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
);
```

It will display :

> 0.20

Or like stated in the question comments, you can also create directly the `BigDecimal` from a String :

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the `int` by a `float`value to give to it a floating number representation and assign it to a floating number.

```
float number2 = number1/100F;
```